# Getting started with VirtoCommerce

Tags: virtocommerce

I try to start an e-Commerce store.
I deployed VirtoCommerce to azure (2 apps).
I have VisualStudio on my pc.
Should I have VirtoCommerce on my pc too?
Sharon

Answer (score 1):

If you have deployed Virto Commerce from GitHub and do not wish to add some functionality - you do not need Virto Commerce source code on your PC.